# Accessing values from user-defined functions

Tags: c, pointers, user-defined-functions

I've got a (I think) pretty easy question that I need help with. I'm working on learning pointers with called user-defined functions in C.

I've got two functions, my main() and another which pulls certain data from a file, read_file(). Read_file() pulls data from a specified file - an integer, (coeff_num) and a series of values (coeff_values) - and prints out the data. Then main() is meant to reprint this data as a check, to ensure that it's being called correctly in order to perform further calculations.

My problem is this: everything is printing out fine in the read_file() function. While checking in main(), data_num is printing out fine, but data_values isn't.

The code (with some irrelevant bits edited out, mainly error checking stuff) is as follows:

```
int read_file(int *data_num, double **data_values, char *filename);
int main()
{

    int data_num;
    double **data_values;

    char *filename[] = {/*FILES*/}; 

    read_fule(&data_num, data_values, *filename);       

    printf("Check Number:\n%u\n", data_num);
    printf("Check Values:\n);

    for(int i = 0; i<data_num; i++)
    {
        printf("%u\t", data_values[i]);
    }
return(0);
}
```

and:

```
int read_file(int *data_num, double **data_values, char *filename)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "rb");  //Opening file

/*  Error checking code here - see if file opens, find length
    return if not long enough, etc */

//Find number of values
    char buffer_n[4];
    fread(buffer_n, 4, 1, fp);                                  
    int result = buffer_n[0]|(buffer_n[1] << 8)|(buffer_n[2] << 16)|(buffer_n[3] << 24);    //Change endian
    *data_num = result;

/* Instructed to allocate memory */
    data_values = malloc(8*result); //Allocating memory 

//Reads data values
    fread(data_values, 8, result, fp); 
//Prints results as float
     printf("Number of data values: %d \n", result); 
    for(int i=0; i<result; i++)
    {
        printf("%0.3f\t", data_values[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

I'm fairly certain that this is an issue with my pointers. For the program, I have to use malloc() when reading data_values, and read_file has to have the prototype of: int read_file(int *data_num, double **data_values, char *filename). Can someone give me some guidance about where I've messed up?

Cheers for any help, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your `result`, it may be too large for allocating memory.

Comment: The value of result? That's usually around 30(%d) in the files that I'm reading.

Comment: Few points: malloc() returns void pointer so you need to type cast it to the desired pointer, another thing malloc() is returning just a pointer so pointer to pointer doesn't make sense. All malloc() should have respective free() calls

Comment: Yes, I've actually been thinking since I posted that my implementation of malloc() might be a part of the issue. I've been looking at some reference pages, though I still haven't quite worked out how to properly fix it yet. Thank you for confirming that it isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

I set `result = 30` as you told me, changed a few places, and I think now it works fine.

I think you don't need `double**` pointer, what you need is `double*` pointer.

And you need cast the `void*` to `double*`:

```
data_values = (double*)malloc(8*result); //Allocating memory
```

This code works fine:

```
//data_values should be defined as double*
int read_file(int *data_num, double *data_values, char *filename)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "rb");  //Opening file

/*  Error checking code here - see if file opens, find length
    return if not long enough, etc */

//Find number of values
    char buffer_n[4];
    size_t i;//added
    fread(buffer_n, 4, 1, fp);                                  
    //int result = buffer_n[0]|(buffer_n[1] << 8)|(buffer_n[2] << 16)|(buffer_n[3] << 24);    //Change endian
    int result = 30;
    *data_num = result;

/* Instructed to allocate memory */
    data_values = (double*)malloc(8*result); //Allocating memory 


//Reads data values
    fread(data_values, 8, result, fp); 

//Prints results as float
    printf("Number of data values: %d \n", result); 
    for(int i=0; i<result; i++)
    {
        printf("%0.3f\t", data_values[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

**Edit**:

If you want to use `double**`, you can try this solution:

```
/* Instructed to allocate memory */
    data_values[0] = (double*)malloc(8 * result); //Allocating memory 

//Reads data values
    fread(data_values[0], 8, result, fp); 

//Prints results as float
    printf("Number of data values: %d \n", result); 
    for(int i=0; i<result; i++)
    {
        printf("%0.3f\t", data_values[0][i]);
    }
```

But you have to notice that this is not a form, this is still used as an array, so you may change it later according to your situation.

Comment: The program has to use a specific prototype, namely: `int read_file(int *data_num, double **data_values, char *filename)`. So it has to be the `double**` pointer for `data_values`. I _think_ it's because the data_values has to be returned to `main()` in a form that it can be printed and operations can be performed on specific array values?

I'm not sure if the issue is in the way I've implemented the code in `main()` and/or in `read_file()` - I admit that I'm a bit lost, haha. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: I still can't get it to run properly for some reason. Running solely from `read_file()` produces the correct output, but when I am calling `read_file()` in `main()` (as in my initial post - the program has to check the data is called correctly and then print it again), it just crashes after reprinting the correct `data_num` without giving a compiler error. So I think it might have to do with how `coeff_values` is being called in `main()`. Any ideas?

Comment: How about post a sample of your data here, I am not sure what is the expected value of this program.@Grom